# Storing of user passwords, in system file, in public file or in database

Tags: database, security, hash, passwords, storage

I have to create a simple security program that is about storing of passwords and the use of authentication mechanisms. I'm just not sure about what to choose from three selections and why it's better/worse over the others.

To me everyone can be seen secure, if it's done right, some are just easier and a lot faster to implement. The three possibilities I have are:

- Storing passwords in a system file where the operating system will handle the confidentiality and integrity. (Not quite sure how this can be done, as I haven't storing anythings in a system file before)
- Storing passwords in a public file in the program where passwords are hashed + salted (salt is uniqe for every password hash generated)
- Storing passwords in a database and let the dbms handle the protection.

To me the best way if you should handle multiple clients signing up with a username/password, the best way is to use the database where also passwords a hashed + salted in it.

Can any of you make some comments how it can be done/pro/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so much about *where* to store the passwords, it is rather about *how* you store them.

If you can store hashes, because you only need to verify the passwords, then you should absolutely use slow password-hash functions like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2, most implementations add a unique salt on their own.

If you need to retrieve the plaintext passwords, because you must login into a 3rd party system, then you should take all possible measures to protect them (encrypting the db/file, require access privileges). The most safe solution is, when the user enters a master key whenever he wants to access the password storage, so the system itself is not able to decrypt them.